# How can I scroll a scrollView using a mouse drag with famo.us?

Tags: famo.us

I would like to be able to scroll a scrollView using a regular mouse drag on a desktop computer. Unfortunately currently the scrollView does only take mouse scroll and touch gestures to be moved. How could I make it work using a regular mouse drag i.e. click drag then release ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve such by using the MouseSync class. The GenericSync used by scrollview is using only TouchSync and ScrollSync. If you create your own MouseSync class you can pipe the surfaces to mouseSync and scrollview then pipe mouseSync to scrollview. Here is the example. Good Luck!

```
var Engine      = require('famous/core/Engine');
var Surface     = require('famous/core/Surface');
var Scrollview  = require('famous/views/Scrollview');
var MouseSync   = require('famous/inputs/MouseSync');

var context = Engine.createContext();

var surfaces = [];

var scrollview = new Scrollview();

scrollview.sequenceFrom(surfaces);

var mouseSync = new MouseSync({direction:1});

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var surface = new Surface({
    size:[undefined,200],
    properties:{
      backgroundColor:'hsl('+(i*360/30)+',100%,50%)'
    }
  });

  surfaces.push(surface);

  surface.pipe(mouseSync);
  surface.pipe(scrollview);

};

mouseSync.pipe(scrollview);
context.add(scrollview);
```

Comment: where I can see all available options for MouseSync() constructor?
I can not find it in docs: https://famo.us/docs/inputs/MouseSync

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use the FlexScrollView which supports mouse-events out of the box:

```
var scrollView = new FlexScrollView({
  mouseMove: true
});
```

https://github.com/IjzerenHein/famous-flex/blob/master/tutorials/FlexScrollView.md
https://github.com/IjzerenHein/famous-flex